# k-way triangle set intersection and triangulation

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry

If we have K sets of potentially overlapping triangles, what is a computationally efficient way of computing a new, non-overlapping set of triangles?

For example, consider this problem:

[image: Tesselation]

Here we have 3 triangle sets A, B, C, with some mutual overlap, and wish to obtain the non-overlapping sets A', B', C', AB, AC, BC, ABC, where for example the triangles in AC would contain the surfaces where there is exclusive overlap among A and C; and A' would contain the surfaces of A which do not overlap any other set.

Comment: I'd suggest breaking this down into two phases: first compute a set of non-overlapping polygons; then triangulate polygons as necessary to obtain triangles. The latter problem is well-researched and there are lots of resources on the web. The first is not as common a problem, but I suspect there are lots of resources for that as well. You need to decide whether the result should include shapes that are not part of any of the original triangles but are closed in by the original triangles (like the gap that would form by shifting the blue triangle a bit to the right).

Comment: You basically want to find the union polygon and triangulate it.  Both can be done using a sweep-line algorithm.  You may be able to combine the operations into a single pass.

Comment: @VaughnCato I'm not sure if union is the correct operator for the above requirements (identity needs to be preserved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I (also) propose a two step approach.

**1. Find the intersection points of all triangle sides.**

As pointed out in the comments, this is a well-researched problem, typically approached with line sweep methods. Here is a [very nice overview](http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html), look especially at the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm.

**2. Triangulate with Constrained Delaunay.**

I think Polygon Triangulation as suggested by @Claudiu cannot solve your problem as it cannot guarantee that all original edges are included. Therefore, I suggest you look at [Constrained Delaunay triangulations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation). These allow you to specify edges that *must* be included in your triangulation, even if they would not be included in an unconstrained Delaunay or polygon triangulation. Furthermore, there are implementations that allow you to specify a non-convex border of your triangulation outside of which no triangles are generated. This also seems to be a requirement in your case.

Implementing Constrained Delaunay is non-trivial. There is however, a somewhat dated but [very nice C implementation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) of available from a CMU researcher (including a command line tool). See [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.research.html) for the theory of this specific algorithm. This algorithm also supports specification of a border. Note that the linked algorithm can do more than just Constrained Delaunay (namely quality mesh generation), but it can be configured not to add new points, which amounts to Constrained Delaunay.

**Edit** See comments for another implementation.

Comment: A constrained delaunay solver with implementations in several languages is available under the BSD license at https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/

Answer (score 2):

If you want something a bit more straight forward, faster to implement, and significantly less code... I'd recommend just doing some simple [polygon clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman) like the old software rendering algorithms used to do (especially since you're only dealing with triangles as your input).  As briefly mentioned by a couple of other people, it involves splitting each triangle at the point where every other ***segment*** intersects it.

Triangles are easy, because splitting a triangle at a given plane always results in just 1 or 2 new ones (2 or 3 total).  If your data set is rather large, you could introduce a quad-tree or other form of spacial organization in order to find the intersecting triangles faster as the new ones get added.

[image]

Granted, this would generate more polygons than the suggested [Constrained Delaunay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation) algorithm.  But many of those algorithms don't do well with overlapping shapes and would require you to know your silhouette segments, so you'd be doing much of the same work anyhow.

And if fewer resulting triangles is a requirement, you can always do a merging pass at the end (adding neighbor information during the clipping to speed that portion up).

Anyway, good luck!

Comment: @jbaylina Ha! You're right... sorry, forgot to draw one of my lines there.  But you get the idea.  :)

Comment: @jbaylina Nice, I still had the image on my desktop... edited my response!  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: For those of you that have to solve this problem in applications with realtime requirements, the approach suggested by @Mattingly has proven to be somewhat more feasible for small inputs

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a special case of what computational geometers call "an arrangement."  The [CGAL Library](http://cgal.org) has extensive and efficent arrangement handling routines.  If you check [this part of the documentation](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Arrangement_on_surface_2/Chapter_main.html#Section_32.8), you'll see that you can declare an empty arrangement, then insert triangles to divide the 2d plane into disjoint faces.  As others have said, you'll then need to triangulate the faces that aren't already triangles.  Happily CGAL also provides the routines to do this.  [This example of constrained Delaunay triangulation](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_37.8.2) is a good place to start.

CGAL attempts to use the most efficient algorithms available that are practical to implement.  In this case it looks like you can achieve O((n + k) log n) for an arrangment with n edges (3 times the number of triangles in your case) with k intersection.  The algorithm uses a general technique called "sweep line".  A vertical line is swept left-to-right with "events" computed and processed along the way.  Events are edge endpoints and intersections.  As each event is processed, a cell of the arrangement is updated.

Delaunay algorithms are typically O(n log n) for n vertices.  There are several common algorithms, easily looked up or found in the CGAL references.

Even if you can't use CGAL in your work (e.g. for licensing reasons), the documentation is full of sources on the underlying algorithms: arrangements and constrained Delaunay algorithms.

Beware however that both arrangments and triangulations are notoriously hard to implement correctly due to floating point error.  Robust versions often depend on rational arithmetic (available in CGAL).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches.

A more general approach is treating your input as just a set of lines and splitting the problem in two:

1. Polygon Detection. Take the set of lines your initial triangles make and get a set of non-overlapping polygons. [This paper](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aKXjmUkopCAoJ%3awww.researchgate.net/publication/2933997_Polygon_Detection_from_a_Set_of_Lines/file/79e41507ddec7cc0ae.pdf+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgY81w6Gsi8X6NnMT2PH0IubL8fyY4rn5w5sPd5efuwqsfkdXxFhpKuese17ojwK9Kx9QLF5xkQCjJF_Zh5v89chm-Efw9bpe7fl1RwDwQ-efndPk4BEMK3Cj8vxWS0catetglM&sig=AHIEtbRYDap4Ud9a7OPfjbJ6F0Az8cpWnw) offers an O((N + M)^4) approach, were N is the number of line segments and M the number of intersections, which does seem a bit slow unfortunately...
2. [Polygon Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation). Take each polygon from step 1 and triangulate it. This takes O(n log* n) which is practically O(n).

Another approach is to do do a custom algorithm. Solve the problem for intersecting two triangles, apply it to the first two input triangles, then for each new triangle, apply the algorithm to all the current triangles with the new one. It seems even for two triangles this isn't that straightforward, though, as there are several cases (might not be exhaustive):

1. No points of the triangle are in any other trianle.

   1. No intersection
   2. Jewish star
   3. Two perpendicular spikes
2. One point of one triangle is contained in the other
3. Each triangle contains one point of the other
4. Two points of one triangle are in the other
5. Three points of one are in the other - one is fully contained

etc... no, it doesn't seem like that is the right approach. Leaving it here anyway for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on the comment from Ted Hopp, this should be possible by first computing a planar subdivision in which each bounded face of the output is associated with one of the sets A', B', C', AB, AC, BC, ABC, or "none".  The second phase is then to triangulate the (possibly non-convex) faces in each set.

Step 1 could be performed in O((N + K) log N) time using a variation of the [Bentley-Ottmann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) sweep line algorithm in which the current set is maintained as part of the algorithm's state.  This can be determined from the line segments that have already been crossed and their direction.

Once that's done, the disjoint polygons for each set can then be broken into monotone pieces in O(N log N) time which in turn can be triangulated in O(N) time.

If you haven't already, pick up a copy of "Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications" by de Berg et al.